# How to insert into table with many to many relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i'm using an excel file to add the data. I'm trying to insert user information along with a user country which is on a second table, which references the country table, something like this:

USERS>USER_COUNTRY>COUNTRIES.

i'm inserting this data with a controller on laravel and can insert the user information fine but not this extra field.

Depending on what i try to do to insert the user_country it doesn't insert it at all but still inserts the other user information.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $users = $request->all();
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $dbUser = $this->getUser($user['USERNAME']);
            Log::error($dbUser);
            $dbUser->name = $user['NOMBRE'];
            $dbUser->user_name = $user['USERNAME'];
            $dbUser->email = $user['CORREO'];
            $dbUser->last_name = $user['APELLIDO'];
            $dbUser->password = $user['PASSWORD'];
            $this->isSet('TIPO-USUARIO', $user);
            $user_type_id = $this->getUserId($user['TIPO-USUARIO']);
            $dbUser->user_type_id = $user_type_id->id;
            foreach (explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $user['PAIS-USUARIO'])) as $c) {
                $country = $this->getCountry($user);
                Log::error($country);
                $dbUser->countries()->attach($user->countries);
            }
            $dbUser->save();
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error importando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
    }
}
```

the `getCountry` function:

```php
private function getCountry($id)
{
    return Country::where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

these are the tables if they are of any help

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('user_name')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->integer('user_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_types');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('currency_symbol');
        $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('user_country', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
});
```

Comment: Look into the `sync` and `syncWithoutDetaching` functions

Comment: @CaddyDZ i've tried sync, and attach and nothing, so far attach seems to be working the most because it bring the data, syncWithoutDetaching and sync and it doesnt bring that data in

Comment: Check my answer, hope it helps